# javascript change chars in a string

Tags: converters, javascript

I'm trying to convert a char string to an array like this : "

```
var temp = "abcdefg
```

and I want to get `temp = 0123456`
when:

```
a=0
b=1
c=2
d=3
e=4
f=5
g=6
```

any idea?
Thanks,

Comment: Convert into an array with ```split```, iterate that array to make another array with the values, and convert this second array to a string with ```join('')```. Please give it a try before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var letters = {
    a: '0',
    b: '1',
    c: '2',
    d: '3',
    e: '4',
    f: '5',
    g: '6'
};

var input = "abcdefg";
var result= input.split('').map(function(letter) {
    return letters[letter];
}).join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp.split("").map ( function (e) { return e.charCodeAt(0)-97 }).join("")
```

Comment: I would have picked ```'a'.charCodeAt(0)``` instead of 97 for better lisibility

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = "abcdefg"
var tempArray = temp.split("")

tempArray[2] // -> "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = "abcdefg";
var arr = temp.split("");

var result =[];
arr.forEach(function(item,index,arr){
  result.push(index);
});

result --> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
result.join('') --> "0123456"
```

Comment: You'll get the same result when `temp = "gfedcba"`. You're just returning the indexes, not using the characters for anything.